# Should I include W2 form with 1040x (amended tax return)?

Tags: income-tax

I am amending tax return in order to include 1099-R. Should I attach W2 along with 1099-R with 1040x?

Thanks

Comment: This is the fourth question today that you've asked that can easily be obtained from the IRS site or other sources.  While I appreciate questions with easy answers and am happy to help, I would recommend reading the instructions with each form to see if your questions are answered there.  If you're nervous that you're going to do something wrong you might be better off dealing with a tax preparer. This is just a Q&A site and not an authoritative source for tax help.

Comment: ^5th question actually.

Answer (score 2):

Per [TurboTax](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2778046-when-sending-in-my-amended-1040x-do-i-need-to-send-all-the-w-2s-1099s-etc-or-only-the-one-that-i-received-late-and-was-therefore-not-included-in-the-original-e-filing):

> You need only attach the forms that support the changes that you've
>   made to your tax return as reflected on the 1040-X. If you just
>   received another W-2 or 1099 after you filed you tax return, then you
>   would need to attach those forms.

So if your change is related to only the 1099-R, then no, you don't need to attach your W-2, assuming that information is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I attach W2 along with 1099-R with 1040x?

Only if a change to the W-2 is a reason for the amended return.

From the [1040X instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040x/ch01.html) (emphasis added):

> ## Assembling Your Return
>
> Assemble any schedules and forms behind Form 1040X in order of the
> “Attachment Sequence No.” shown in the upper-right corner of the
> schedule or form. If you have supporting statements, arrange them in
> the same order as the schedules or forms they support and attach them
> last. Don’t attach a copy of your original return, correspondence, or
> other items unless required to do so.
>
> Attach to the front of Form 1040X:
>
> - A copy of any Form W-2, Form W-2c, or Form 2439, Notice to Shareholder of Undistributed Long-Term Capital Gains, **that support
>   changes made on this return**;
> - A copy of any Form W-2G, Certain Gambling Winnings, or 1099-R **that support changes made on this return**, but only if tax was withheld; and
> - A copy of any Form 1042-S, Foreign Person's U.S. Source Income Subject to Withholding; Form SSA-1042S, Social Security Benefit
>   Statement (Nonresident Aliens); Form RRB-1042S, Payments by the
>   Railroad Retirement Board (Nonresident Aliens); or Form 8288-A,
>   Statement of Withholding on Dispositions by Foreign Persons of U.S.
>   Real Property Interests, **that support changes made on this return**.
>
> Attach to the back of Form 1040X any Form 8805, Foreign Partner's
> Information Statement of Section 1446 Withholding Tax, **that supports
> changes made on this return**.